# solve function in sympy (python)

Tags: python-2.7, sympy

I want to calculate a variable( 'w' in the program) by calculating determinate of a matrix (witch include the variable) equal to zero. but I don't know why it doesn't work for l=0.01 but works for l=0.0.
I use version 7.4.1 of Sympy and be very happy if sombody answered me!

```
 from sympy import *
 import random as ra

 w = Symbol('w')
 l=0.01
 d1=ra.uniform(-l,l)
 d2=ra.uniform(-l,l)
 d3=ra.uniform(-l,l)
 d4=ra.uniform(-l,l)
 d5=ra.uniform(-l,l)
 d6=ra.uniform(-l,l)
 S = Matrix([[ -d1*w**2 - w**2 + 2.,-1,0,0,0],
          [-1.,-d2*w**2 - w**2 + 2.,-1,0,0],
          [0,-1.,-d3*w**2 - w**2 + 2.,-1,0],
          [0,0,-1.,-d4*w**2 - w**2 + 2.,-1],
         [0,0,0,-1.,-d5*w**2 - w**2 + 2.]
    ])


    determ = S.berkowitz_det()
    wha = solve(determ,w)
    print wha
```

Comment: How does it not work?

Comment: I don't know what you mean, did you try it?

Comment: Include more information about how something doesn't work in your questions. Don't require people to run your code to see what is happening. Otherwise your questions might be closed for being too low quality.

Comment: Yes exactly, Excuse me for asking question wrongly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `solve(determ, w, rational=False)`.